# Normalize multiple ElasticSearch search queries

Tags: elasticsearch, search, lucene

I have a complex query in ElasticSearch looking at different fields. This works very well so far, if you have only one query. I would now like to display several results from different searchobjects queries (e.g. results for search object1, search object2, search object3) for an overview page and sort them according to relevance (in this case the _score).
I also use different boostings on different fields, I quickly get very large _score values ​​from ES. For SearchObject1, the values ​​can be between 200-30000. For search object2 however between 1-10.

So far I have worked with a pilot query and look at what were typical scores in the past and then normalize them.
This gives okay-ish results, but maybe someone has faced a similar problem and found a more elegant and better solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, because Elastic scores are based on tf-idf like algorithms, there's no cap on how big a score can get. So either you need to move to things like constant score (in case you're not handling text) or you need to somehow turn the potentially large number to a capped number by applying a sigmoid function to turn the score into a range like `[0-1]`.

Secondly, there's no general answer to how to combine different set of scores. In big complex apps usually people do some kind of machine learning approach to balance them. For smaller case you can just try giving different weights to each score and observe.